# How to make loop inside a function in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function which plays audio file in os. I want to keep playing the audio on a loop when the function is called, and it should only stop unless another close function is called.

---

```
def music:
    cast=1
    while cast=1:
        os.system('mpg123 /home/debian/sample.mp3')

def close:
    cast=0

global cast
```

---

I have another function which is calling close()

**EDIT**: If I put my sound playing command like this:

```
os.system('mpg123 --loop 3 /home/debian/sample.mp3')
```

Then after playing audio 3 times, the program does go to **close** function.

How can I make it goto **close** function as soon as I get cast=0?

This gets stuck on while loop and keeps playing the audio file forever.

Any ideas on how to make it work?

Thanks

Comment: How are you calling `close()`?

Comment: You need to put `global cast` inside each of the functions. It doesn't have any effect if you write it outside a function.

Comment: You need parentheses after your function definitions, otherwise SyntaxErrors are raised

Comment: `while cast=1` should be `while cast == 1`. `=` is assignment, `==` is comparison.

Comment: Or just write `while cast:`

Comment: How do you expect your `while` loop to be exited?

Comment: @Barmar all of those suggestions boil down to the fact that there is no exit condition on the while loop

Comment: @Barmar I have another function which is calling close()

Comment: How are you imagining that this other function can do anything, when your program is stuck in a `while` loop?  That would require multithreading, but there's no sign of that in the fragment of code you posted.

Comment: @jasonharper please see my edit above. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Each function that changes the value must declare the variable to be global; otherwise, it's merely a local variable with the same name.

Also, if you're using a simple boolean flag, then use boolean values.

```
def music:
    global cast
    cast = True
    while cast:
        os.system('mpg123 /home/debian/sample.mp3')

def close:
    global cast
    cast = False
```

Comment: "Didn't work" is not a problem description.  You still haven't provided the code you're using to call `close` in parallel with `music` executing.  You have to have some sort of multiprocessing.